# Store Helpers functions in mysql Table Undefined variable $employee_id

Tags: laravel, function, migration, helper

I'm working on Laravel and I have functions in the helper. I want to store the functions in the data base (mirgation).

Ex function in the helper :

```
function PayrollSalary($employee_id, $employor_id)
```

I can't  store the below line when I migrate the database. I have an error message (Undefined variable $employee_id).

```
DB::table('payroll_model_items')->insert(array(
  'code'=>"BaseSal", 
  'name'=>"Base Salary", 
  'value'=>"<div>{{PayrollSalary($employee_id, $employor_id)}}</div>",  
  'sequence'=>"0000101",
  'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
  'updated_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:m:s')
));
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: is `$employee_id` defined?

Comment: It is related to employee id.. The  code is starting by  PayrollSalary($employee_id, $employor_id){
        $contract = Contract::where('employee_id', $employee_id)
   .....